# How to use Colors in SwiftUI the right way? (Specially for Applications with Light and DarkMode)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a small Question about SwiftUI and programming for Darkmode.
I am programming in swift for like 4 month by now and I want to start programming for Dark Mode and Light Mode.

In SwiftUI there are a few methods to Color something, for example a Text.
If I want to color the Foreground from the Text Green there are the following ways to do it (correct me if I am wrong):

```
.foregroundColor(.green)
.foregroundColor(Color.green)
.foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.green))
.foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen)) <- I usually do this
```

In Light Mode, this works, but if I switch to dark Mode, some of my Components are colored differently, for Example if I have a black foreground, this foreground is now white.
But with some other Components, its black.

Can you guys give me an Example how I should properly program for Darkmode? Which of these 4 Methods above should I use? Or is there a different way? Or do you have other Tips for Coloring Fore- and Background with SwiftUI?

Note: I am not trying to find a Solution for a specific Problem, I just want to understand how all of the Colors and different Methods of coloring works in SwiftUI. I already Googled stuff but didn't find something that I understood, so I try my luck here :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first, second and last line shows the same color. The third line is different.

`.green` and `Color.green` are synonyms anyway. In SwiftUI the basic colors (`.red`, `.green` ...) are the same as the corresponding `.systemRed`, `.systemGreen` ... colors in UIKit.

You can prove it by running this code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(UIColor.systemGreen))
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(UIColor.green))
        }
    }
} 

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
        ContentView()
            .colorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

The first two colors are identical but slightly different in light and dark mode. The third color is fixed in both modes. There is no reason to use the `system...` colors of `UIColor` in SwiftUI.

You can create custom colors with different appearance for light and dark mode in the Asset Catalog and use it with [`init(_:bundle:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/init(_:bundle:))

Comment: Thank you, this was pretty helpful <3

Answer (score 3):

Color is a view in SwiftUI.

UIColor is subclass of UIKit.

You can initialize Color with UIColor, and standard colors that support dark mode have "system" prefix `systemBlue`, `systemGreen`...

So if you want to use Apple's standard color supporting Dark mode, you should use the 4th method

```
.foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen))
```

P/s: You can use the Color Assets then initialize with its name

```
.foregroundColor(Color("colorName"))
```

Comment: Your P/s is quite nice ^^ didn't knew that this also works, but what should I use if I want to have it black, in Dark and Light Mode? Should I then use the other 3 or is there also a difference between those 3? And Thank you :)